# Where do I find a MongoDB PID?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Where can I find the process ID for a mongo database? I have tried to search it up but, I cannot find anything on stack overflow that answer this question. Do I use the MongoDB terminal or any command or can I find it on the website itself?

Comment: How do you plan to use this ID?

Comment: You can try `sudo service mongodb  status` where you find `Main PID: <process ID>`

Comment: That should be in the `pid` field of `serverStatus` if you can connect to the running instance.

Comment: Since v4.4, mongod.conf  `processManagement.pidFilePath` entry is [deleted from source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/8d463a6789d68e2fc39b93346152e1b4a626e14a#diff-ab9a9d7a9c95cf7bf84ef590bc995c073414f01f18eb7be13f30e5f8c9117834) because of OS dependency according to the [doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/configuration-options/#processmanagement-options).  This is the reason why I also looked to know PID for [logrotation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/rotate-log-files/).  @strausd answer helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try these two commands:

```
pidof mongod
pgrep mongod
```

Comment: pgrep worked for me on a mac terminal thanks! while `pidof` was not recognized

Answer (score 0):

You can run mongod with the parameter `--pidfilepath` to specify the file where the process ID will be stored.

See `mongod --help` for details:

```
--pidfilepath arg                     Full path to pidfile (if not set, no 
                                      pidfile is created)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the `top` command on your terminal if you are using Mac to find the list of all ids of processes including mongo database: